Object not in the same position when rendering animation vs viewport
I have this animation of a dice falling using rigid body. When rendering the animation the dice is in another position than in viewport (exemple at frame 2:the dice is in frame in viewport but not in render).This is not the case for every frame, (I've tried a couple doing image rendering) and can't seem to find a pattern. Does anyone have any idea? I've attached the blender file: 
 

weird, it works for me, this is what it gives for frame 2: https://i.postimg.cc/P5ZMS0Cm/1.jpg

Try to run the entire animation from frame 0 first.
If it still happens, maybe try to bake the animation?
